# How to prevent opening a link of the submenu when tapping the menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, multi-level

I have this problem with this basic multi-level **responsive** menu I made while using `:hover` (I'm not a profesional. I'm just someone who knows some html, css and wants to create a theme for a favourite website).

When using a mobile device (Chrome for Android):

- if I tap the second menu entry  (I still haven't mod the link for the responsive mode of the first menu "Forums"), the submenu opens just fine
- If I tap the third menu entry, its submenu will open, but in the process **it will also tap a link inside the submenu**.

I pressume it is because the height of the menu container changes when each submenu is opened and when the submenu is opened the tap is still active and it clicks a link of the submenu.

How do I stop that from happening?

This is the website where the theme in construction is: http://etrostruewowdesigncomplete2.esy.es/phpBB3/index.php

The menu itself is still not finished (i have to hide some links in responsive modes and icons). The menu container opens when taping on the search icon.

This the menu. For example, when opening Community's submenu with a tap, the link highlighted is also taped in the process:

Here is a screenshot of the menu on small screen :
[image: responsive menu]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I applied them.

Comment: Even opening the menu (touching the *magnifying glass icon* ) on Android Chrome send me to the `search` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with onclick events for the menu. Hover will just not do it.